# Find the sum of the areas of the regions bounded by the graphs of $f(x) = 1 + x + e^{x^2-2x}$ and $x^4 -7x^2+6x+2$

Tags: integration, polynomials, exponential-function, area

[image]

Hi everyone,

I am trying to attempt this question, but don't know how to integrate the exponential term. Any help with this question and the method to solve it would be gratefully received.

Comment: You can't integrate the exponential term unless you want to use the imaginary error function.https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E%28x%5E2-2x%29

Comment: That's what I thought @JoshuaWang - so does this mean this question (I've included the picture from the textbook as well) is impossible to solve using high school maths?

Comment: @JoshuaWang:  Not only is the integral not possible via elementary functions, the intersection points aren't expressible in closed form (other than the intersection at $x = 0$.)

Comment: You are probably supposed to use a calculator to approximate both the intersection points and the integrals.